# How can I use macros in \addcontentsline?

Tags: table-of-contents, sections-paragraphs, unnumbered-sections

A word of warning to begin with: I doubt I have fully grasped `\def`, `\edef`, `\let` or `\expandafter` and feel utterly stumped after a long string of attempts to solve the following problem.

I would like to add custom labels to section titles, i.e. there are different parts to my document and title strings should reflect that. Section titles should be preceded by A1, A2, A3, ... K1, K2, K3, ... D1, D2, D3, ... depending on the counter that is supplied to a macro `\unit{counter}{title}`.

Creating counters is no problem, conditionals work and adding a starred section command to suppress the default section numbering is straightforward. All hell breaks loose when \addcontentsline comes into play, telling me that `\endcsname` has been inserted (In some variations of `\def` and `\expandafter` in my code I ended up with an error saying that the very section macro I had defined was undefined — although the `hyperref` package seems to have caused some of the issues there). Be that as it may, below is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{parta}
\setcounter{parta}{0}
\newcounter{partb}
\setcounter{partb}{0}

\newcommand\unit[2]{%
  \def\tag{A}
  \def\cnt{#1}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{morph}}%
    {\def\tag{A}}%
    {%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{syntax}}%
      {\def\tag{B}}%
      {}%
    }%
  \def\numtag{\refstepcounter{\cnt}\tag\arabic{\cnt}}
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\unittitle{\numtag{} #2}
  \section*{\unittitle}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\unittitle}}

\begin{document}
\unit{parta}{foo}
\unit{partb}{bar}
\end{document}
```

The error I receive is

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.27 \unit{parta}{foo}
```

I am aware I could probably achieve something like this using the `titlesec` package or similar, but the process seemed simple enough at the outset. I assume this can be easily resolved and I am being stupid. Aren’t I just adapting strings that are expanded before being shipped out to auxiliary files? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to the site.  One immediate problem is that `\tag` is used by the popular `amsmath` package.  Should probably rename your macro.

Answer (score 2):

You're making things a bit too complicated. There's no need to condition on whatever you're passing as you can define "prefixes" to these numbers/counter in the following way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\parta}{A}% Prefix for parta
\newcommand{\partb}{B}% Prefix for partb
\newcounter{parta}
\newcounter{partb}

\newcommand\unit[2]{%
  \stepcounter{#1}% Step counter
  \section*{\csname #1\endcsname\arabic{#1} #2}% Section title is "<counter prefix><counter> <title>"
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\csname #1\endcsname\arabic{#1} #2}% Add to ToC
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\unit{parta}{foo}
\unit{partb}{bar}
\unit{parta}{baz}

\end{document}
```

The above works because content written to the ToC is expanded, fully, and can be since the definition passed to is very simple. In your example - `\unittitle` - was comprised of `\numtag`, which included a `\refstepcounter` - a macro that does a lot of background calculations and definitions.

---

In fact, LaTeX provides a fairly easy way to handle what you're after. There is a difference between the value of a counter and it's representation. The value is something internal to LaTeX, while the representation could be `\roman`, or `\arabic`, or `\alph`abetic. So, you could add to this representation a prefix by redefining `\the<counter>`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{parta}
\newcounter{partb}
\renewcommand{\theparta}{A\arabic{parta}}
\renewcommand{\thepartb}{B\arabic{partb}}

\newcommand\unit[2]{%
  \stepcounter{#1}% Step counter
  \section*{\csname the#1\endcsname{} #2}% Section title is "<counter prefix><counter> <title>"
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\csname the#1\endcsname{} #2}% Add to ToC
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\unit{parta}{foo}
\unit{partb}{bar}
\unit{parta}{baz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{parta}
\newcounter{partb}
\newcounter{partc}

\newcommand\unit[2]{%
  \def\mytag{A}
  \setcounter{#1}{\value{#1}}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{partc}}%
    {\def\mytag{C}}%
    {%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{partb}}%
      {\def\mytag{B}}%
      {}%
    }%
  \refstepcounter{#1}%
  \edef\numtag{\mytag\arabic{#1}}
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\unittitle\expandafter{\numtag{} #2}
  \section*{\unittitle}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\unittitle}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\hrulefill

\unit{parta}{foo}
\unit{parta}{foo-ex}
\unit{partb}{bar}
\unit{partb}{bar none}
\unit{partb}{barbel}
\unit{partc}{foo-bar}
\end{document}
```

[image]